# Create video from CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new to ios, i am working on an application in which i need to create a video from animation performed. I am using CAKeyframeAnimation for performing the animation. Kindly tell me where to go next .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AVExportSession for creating videos using avmutablecomposition, AVMutableComposition supports core animation tool in which you can perform any animation in your video. For more reference, refer this http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answer, In this tutorial its using already existing video, but i want to create new video for the animation that is performed. Please, if possible give me some sample codes. Waiting for your answer. Thanx.

Comment: hi,  i found one complication while using this tutorial, The animation  geometry is different than the default. The animation is working opposite to the one expected and the video resolution is affecting the animation.it will be great thank if you can help me with that. Thank you..

Comment: Can you tell by which you are performing animation? Is it a video or Image or anything else. So I can tell you more about it.

Comment: hi, i am animating UIImageViews in path drawn by user. i want the animation to be added in the video.